# Android error while building the Alexa auto SDK

Tags: android, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build the Alexa auto sdk in Mac OS High Sierra. I am able to successfully build the docker environment required on Mac for the Alexa Auto SDK Builder. While installing the NDK I am getting the following error in terminal `

```
*******************
*** Docker Mode ***
*******************

NOTE: Run Docker image...
NOTE: SDK Version: 1.2.0
NOTE: Start building for androidarm...
NOTE: Android toolchains will be installed: /workdir/android
NOTE: Checking Android toolchain installation (armeabi-v7a/22)...
NOTE: Installing NDK (android-ndk-r16b)...
NOTE: Downloading file android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip
--2018-10-31 05:39:02--  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 216.58.203.142, 2404:6800:4009:802::200e
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|216.58.203.142|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify dl.google.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=192.168.86.1’:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
To connect to dl.google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
ERROR: Android toolchain setup failed
```

`I tried` `wget --no-check-certificate https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip` `
and downloaded the NDK but the issue is still persisting. Please help as I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

We have downloaded Alexa-auto-SDK 1.6.

we used the following steps below. Please update docker, my case everything fine working.

```
mac$ ./builder/build.sh oe -t androidarm --android-api 26

*******************************************************************************
The scripts provided herein will retrieve several third-party libraries,
environments, and/or other software packages at build-time
("External Dependencies") from third-party sources. These are terms and
conditions that you need to agree to abide by if you choose to build the
External Dependencies. Licenses for the External Dependencies may be found at
builder/README.md. If you do not agree with every term and condition
associated with the External Dependencies, enter “QUIT” in the command line
when prompted by the script.
*******************************************************************************

Type "QUIT" to exit the script now, press ENTER to continue: 

\e[1mNOTE\e[0m: Builder only runs within Docker with macOS host
\e[1mNOTE\e[0m: Switching to Docker mode...

*******************
*** Docker Mode ***
*******************

+++ dirname /Users/mac/MetroProject/Android1.5/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/scripts/run-docker.sh
++ cd /Users/mac/MetroProject/Android1.5/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/scripts
++ pwd
+ THISDIR=/Users/mac/MetroProject/Android1.5/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/scripts
+ source /Users/mac/MetroProject/Android1.5/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/scripts/common.sh
++ '[' -z /Users/mac/MetroProject/Android1.5/alexa-auto-sdk/builder ']'
+ VM_HOME=/home/builder
+ IMAGE_REVISION=20190128
+ IMAGE_NAME=aac/ubuntu-base:20190128
+ VOLUME_NAME=buildervolume
+ VOLUME_MOUNT_POINT=/workdir
+ [[ '' != \1 ]]
+ TTY=-t
+ EXTRA_OPTIONS=
+ '[' '!' -z ']'
++ docker images -q aac/ubuntu-base:20190128
+ [[ aad39b28847b == '' ]]
++ docker volume ls
++ grep buildervolume
+ [[ local               buildervolume == '' ]]
+ note 'Run Docker image...'
+ echo -e '\e[1mNOTE\e[0m: Run Docker image...'
\e[1mNOTE\e[0m: Run Docker image...
+ execute_command aac/builder/build.sh oe -t androidarm --android-api 26
+ docker run -i -t --rm -v buildervolume:/workdir -v /Users/mac/MetroProject/Android1.5/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/..:/home/builder/aac -e ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=/workdir/android -e AGL_SDK_BASE=/workdir/agl-sdk -e HOST_PWD=/Users/mac/MetroProject/Android1.5/alexa-auto-sdk -e HOST_SDK_HOME=/Users/mac/MetroProject/Android1.5/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/.. aac/ubuntu-base:20190128 aac/builder/build.sh oe -t androidarm --android-api 26
NOTE: SDK Version: 1.6.0-00002-gb9ee08f-dirty
NOTE: Start building for androidarm...
NOTE: Android toolchains will be installed: /workdir/android
NOTE: Checking Android toolchain installation (armeabi-v7a/26)...
NOTE: Using BUILD_DIR=/workdir/build

                         Welcome to Alexa Auto Builder!


                                             .c;.                               
                                            .lKx.                               
             ':loooooc'   .:c'      .c:.  .;lkKOocc:.   .;looooc,.              
            .:lc;;;:d00l. ,OKc      cK0;  'coOKOocc:. .lOOd:;;cxOk:.            
                    .oKk' ,OKc      :0O;    .dKx.    .oKO;     .l00:            
              .;:::;:dKk' ,OKc      :0O;    .dKx.    ,kKo.      'kKd.           
            'dOxlc::lkKk' ,OKc      :0O;    .dKx.    ,OKo.      .xKd.           
           .dKk'    .lKk' ,OKl.     cKO;    .dKx.    .dKk'      :00c            
           .oKOc...,lkKk' .xKOc'.';cxKO;    .oKOl,,,. 'd0kc,..,lO0l.            
            .:dxxdol;:ol.  'lxkxdol;;lo'     .:dxxdo'  .;ldxxxxdc'              
               ...            ...                          ....                 
                                                            ......              
           ...                                           .',,,;;cc:.            
            .',,..                                          ..  'c:.            
              ..,::;,...                               ...,;;.  'c,             
                 ..,:ccc:;,''......          .....'',;:cc;,..  .:,              
                     ..',:ccllllcccc:::::::ccccllllc:;'..      ..               
                           ...',,;;::::::::;;;,'....                            


Loading cache: 100% |############################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1299 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
NOTE: Multiple providers are available for virtual/nativesdk-libintl (nativesdk-gettext, nativesdk-glibc)
Consider defining a PREFERRED_PROVIDER entry to match virtual/nativesdk-libintl

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.36.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-16.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-linux-androideabi"
MACHINE              = "androidarm"
DISTRO               = "aac"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "1.6.0"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7a vfp thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta-aac-ubuntu      = "1.6:b9ee08ff5e9a88e1554d1d90f3e368d92cd302cf"
meta                 = "HEAD:1b18cdf6b8bdb00ff5df165b9ac7bc2b10c87d57"
meta-aac             
meta-aac-builder     = "1.6:b9ee08ff5e9a88e1554d1d90f3e368d92cd302cf"

Initialising tasks: 100% |#######################################| Time: 0:00:03
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 553 tasks of which 417 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
```

Thank you